# Occuring of UnsatisfiedDependencyException error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have the following code and `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.shopping")` and the package structure is

```
com.project.shopping.Controller
com.project.shopping.configuration
com.project.shopping.entity
com.project.shopping.services
com.project.shopping.dao
```

The error when i run the app is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDaoImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'userDaoImpl' is expected to be of type 'com.project.shopping.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56'
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'userDaoImpl' is expected to be of type 'com.project.shopping.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1148)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFatory;

public List<User> getAllUser() {
    return this.sessionFatory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from user").list();

}
}
```

Is it fine to annotate both the interface  and it's implementation with @Repository and also in the service interface and it's implementation annotating with @Service
UserDao.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao {
public List<User> getAllUser();
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
public interface UserService {
public List<User> listUser();
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
@Autowired 
private UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;
public List<User> listUser() {

    return userDaoImpl.getAllUser();
}
}
```

UserController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
@Autowired
UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value = "/allusers" , produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<User> sayHello(ModelMap model) {

    return userServiceImpl.listUser();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We mostly need to use @Repository, @Service, @Component etc on the Implementation Classes, Spring Create Beans for classes marked with these Annotations.

Also in your *ServiceImpl & *DaoImpl, Usage @Autowire will be mostly on the Interface of the Implementation Class.

Suggesting to

- Remove @Repository from UserDao & @Service from UserService.
- Autowire UserDao & UserService instead of UserDaoImpl & UserServiceImpl in UserServiceImpl & UserController respectively.